# Autofill fields in drupal7

Tags: drupal-7, autofill, entityreference

I'm trying to autofill text fields after selecting an item from select list. What I mean is: first I want user to choose an item from select list and then there will be 3 more text fields and I want to give them distinct values based on which was selected.

Comment: Please, try to be more specific. Maybe add what you have tried and the problems you found.

Comment: I have a content type in which I have a select list. For select list I used taxonomy. The select list is list of companies, and the other fields are textfields. They have information about location, country, and phone of the company. When I choose company it will have its own country, and location and phone so I want to fill them automatically. I tried with hierarchical list, but it didn't worked because there is only one list. I also tried autofill modules, but that also didn't work.  @zuazo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use Drupal "Ajax framework". Please prepare your fields in hook_form_alter function.

```
function hook_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (isset($form['type']) && $form['type']['#value'] . '_node_settings' == $form_id) {
    $form['select_field'] = array(
      '#ajax' => array(
        'callback' => '_mymodule_ajax_example_simplest_callback',
        'wrapper' => 'replace_textfield_div',
       ),
    );

    // This entire form element will be replaced with an updated value.
    $form['textfield_to_autofill'] = array(
      '#prefix' => '<div id="replace_textfield_div">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
    );
  }
}
function _mymodule_ajax_example_simplest_callback(&$form, $form_state) {
  // The form has already been submitted and updated. We can return the replaced
  // item as it is.
  $commands = array();
  if($form_state['values']['select_field'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] == "some_value"){
    $form['textfield_to_autofill'][LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value']['#value'] = "some_value";
    $commands[] = ajax_command_replace("#replace_textfield_div", render($form['textfield_to_autofill']));
  }
  $page = array('#type' => 'ajax', '#commands' => $commands);
  ajax_deliver($page);
}
```

Here helping link for [ajax framework](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!ajax.inc/group/ajax/7.x).